# Julia: fast file write on the fly

Tags: performance, io, julia

I am coding a solver which needs to write to file few numbers at each time step. The time step must be small, thus I need to write the output often..

[This picture shows the code profiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq1P6.png). As you can see, the highlighted IO section takes a conspicuous part of the execution time.

The IO is done as

```
println(out_file, t, " ", v.P[1], " ", v.P[end])
```

where I want to save the first and last element of the vector `P` inside the data structure `v` as well as the value of `t`.

From the profiling seems that the most of the computational time is taken by the `string.jl` function (which is not defined by me).

This make me wonder whether there is more efficient way to write iteratively the output to file.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

**Additional info**

The output file is opened once at the beginning of the execution and left open until the end.
I cannot report the entire code as it is very long, but it is something as

```
out_file = open("file.out", "w")

delta_t = computeDeltaT()
t = 0
while t<T
  P = computeP()

  println(out_file, t, " ", P[1], " ", P[end])

  delta_t = computeDeltaT()
  t += delta_t
end

close(out_file)
```

I need to write iteratively because the solution develops in time and I do not know how delta_t will change. So I cannot pre-allocate P. Also, it would be a huge matrix, something like millions by 5.

**EDIT**

@isebarn by printing every 100 steps indeed reduces the execution time. Also I'll try to add a second worker to handle the IO so I will not lose data.

Comment: Do you need to display the output, or merely  record it?

Comment: @Oxinabox the numbers are directly recorded to file, no display output is needed

Comment: can you provide a bit more details? What immediately comes to mind is that you're opening the file for write, writing into it, and closing it back, every single time a write is performed. You could take a look at the HDF5 package for reading/writing variables in binary format, which might be a bit faster. In addition, why do you need to write the output iteratively? i.e why cant you write it all at once?

Comment: It may be a huge sidestep from what you're prepared to do, but you could just start another worker process to do all your IO work. Another option would be to not write every single time, but every 10/100/1000 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By iteratively do you mean another application/program must be able to read the file in between writes? Otherwise you can just open the stream once then close at the end.

```
f = open(outfile,"w") # do this once
for i in someloop
    # do something
    write(f, "whatever") # write to stream but not flushed to disk
end
close(f) # now everything is flushed to the disk (i.e. now outfile will have changed)
```

If you need to access the file during the process then you can open/close during every iteration (maybe write is faster than println, profile it to check) or you could just open/close the stream every N iterations to balance the two?

**Edit**: 
Source:
http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/networking-and-streams/

Like @isebarn said writing binary to hdf5 may also be faster. Not sure though.

Also also IO is quite often a limiting factor in these sorts of scenarios. The other thing to try is if there is a way to estimate P you could pre-allocate and then trim it?

Comment: by iteratively I mean _at each iteration_ (perhaps not the best term to use). Indeed my code works as you are suggesting. I am profiling the `write` command to see if that improves the running time.

Comment: `write` streams the output to a binary file and it is slightly faster than `println`.